# How to simulate camera midlet in Nokia C6?

Tags: java-me, camera, nokia, mmapi

I need to simulate the behaviour of the default camera midlet from Nokia.

It's for Nokia C6, and I am writing it in J2ME.

I use MMAPI, the problem is the size of VideoControl item, I made it `videoControl.setDisplayFulscreen(true);` but it ain't fullscreen at all, the method setDisplaySize doesn't help, the size of videoControl itself is roughly one third of the display (the rest of desired displaySize is just black), here's a code sample:

```
public CameraCanvas (Evidence_elektromeru midlet, ManagePhotos caller,String name) { 
    super(true);
    this.midlet = midlet;
    this.caller = caller;
    this.name = name;
    this.setFullScreenMode(true);

    try {
        player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://devcam0");
        player.realize();
      //  player.prefetch();
        if (videoControl2 != null) 
                videoControl2.setVisible(false);
        videoControl1 = (VideoControl) player.getControl("VideoControl");
        videoControl1.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO,this);
        videoControl1.setDisplayLocation(0, 0);
        videoControl1.setDisplaySize(360,500);
        }catch (MediaException me2) {
            try {
                videoControl1.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
             }
    catch (Exception e) {}
    finally {
               try {
              player.start();
               } catch (Exception e) {}
              videoControl1.setVisible(true); 


        }
```

Comment: You need to sign your application.

Comment: i have access to camera, but i want my camera to look like default camera in nokia c6. they have widescreen VideoControl all over the display no matter if its landscape of profile mode :(

Comment: Sign you application with VerySign Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
 mCamera = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video");
 mCamera.realize();
 mCamera.prefetch();
```

or you can replace mCamera = Manager.createPlayer("capture://video"); by

```
mCamera = Manager.createPlayer("capture://image");
```